# How to do one liner "if" and "for-loop" together in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

So I have been liking to have my code more clean and I have been stuck into something that might be very easy to do.

Basically what I have done is currently:

```
for raw_product in r.json().get('data'):
    if raw_product.get('countdown') is False:
        print(raw_product.get('url'))
```

and I have been trying to figure out how to make it to one liner. So far I have only come to

```
test = ['{}'.format(raw_product.get('url')) for raw_product in r.json().get('data')]
```

however inside the one liner, there is missing the if statement and I wonder if it possible to apply the if statement inside the `['{}'.format(raw_product.get('url')) for raw_product in r.json().get('data')]` ?

Comment: I can tell you one thing; writing code as as a oneliner does not make you code cleaner. Who ever told you this lied.

Comment: list comprehension construction `[ ... for ... in ... if ...]`

Comment: @Cyclonecode "... does not *always* make your code cleaner"

Comment: @Cyclonecode Oh.. Yikes hahaha, but I guess its a good knowledge to atleast know how to do it ? :D

Comment: @furas Thanks mate! It worked with adding `if raw_product.get('countdown') is False` at the end! :)

Comment: There are many tutorials online showing all the different formats possible to play with with list-comprehension. For example, just here you could do 2

Comment: In this particular case, a one liner might save you a couple lines in the file but it will make it more hard to read. I would leave it as it is.

Comment: `if not raw_product.get(...)` is preferable.

Comment: BTW, it is less fitting to use list comprehension when you don't actually use the resulting list, rather than creating it for the side effect, which in this case is the `print`

Comment: Appreciate all the answers honestly, It is stuff that I wouldn't think of if nobody told me. I always thought the less code the more cleaner when it does the same thing. but I was wrong but you all helped me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this generator :

```
 gen = (repr(x.get('url')) for x in r.json().get('data') if not x.get('countdown'))
```

Or list :

```
li = [repr(x.get('url')) for x in r.json().get('data') if not x.get('countdown')]
```

What makes thise code not clean, is not the comprehension, but  this 
'get' methods. Compare that to :

`li = [x.url for x in r.json_data if not x.countdown]`. Is kind of clearer.

Comment: I think you have a syntax error in the 1st two examples (should be `repr(x.get('url'))`)

Comment: thanks, see how this get methods lead you to errors :d

Comment: Oh! I didnt knew about the repr! This was actually better than I thought, I will mark this as answer :) Thanks mate!

Comment: yeah you d like the urls displayed properly so repr :D

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure it's cleaner, but you can use a generator expression with an `if` filter to get this kind of pattern in one line:

```
[ print(rp.get('url')) for rp in r.json().get('data') if rp.get('countdown') is False ]
```

Note that this has the inefficiency of creating and remembering a whole list of `None` values (the result of every `print` call).

Comment: filling a list with None is not realy optimal

Comment: That's why I've noted that downside! I'd be interested to see other one-line solutions.